# Using a Unit Invariant Parameter in Fixed Effects Regression

Tags: time-series, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, macroeconomics

I'm performing regressions on the relationship between macroeconomic factors and firm survival across industries. I have the real GDP growth rates for each industry and the PRIME rate for the entire United states. This has given me the fixed effects equation:

$$
SURVIVAL_i,_t = \alpha_i + \beta_1rgdp_i,_t + \beta_2prime_t + \epsilon_i,_t
   $$
The parameter for prime is variable across time, but not across units (those being industry). Thus, for any given time t, each unit has the same number for prime. Is this a legitimate model? Am I violating any assumptions used in fixed effects models?

Answer (score 0):

If a variable does not vary over time per unit, it drops out of the calculation so you won't get an estimate for it. Depending on the software you use, the calculation might not be performed and you will have to drop the variable yourself.

If there is little variation over time per unit, the model is in principle computationally estimable, but the estimate for such a variable is not very reliable.